# How could I use the definition of Moving Average, write Python code (using for loops) to calculate an n-period moving average list, called ma?

Tags: python

MAn(t) = (Pt + Pt-1 + ... + Pt-(n-1)) / n

prices : (list) prices data to be used to obtain the moving average

n : (int) number defining moving-average lag (e.g. 252)

ma : (list) moving average data of length N, where first (n-1) values are None

```
def ma(n):
    i=0
    ma=[]
    if i < n - 1:
        ma.append("None" * (n-1-i))
        
    while i < len(prices) - n + 1:
        nn = prices[i:i+n]
        n_average = sum(nn)/n
        ma.append(n_average)
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your code. Remember to [format](/help/formatting) it using a code block

Comment: yes thanks for advice already added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python without any 3rd party libraries:

```py
def moving_average(x, n):
    L = len(x)
    result = (n - 1) * [None]
    for i in range(L - n + 1):
        result.append(sum(x[i:i + n]) / n)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 1))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 2))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 3))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 4))
```

Modern way using list comprehension:

```py
def moving_average(x, n):
    L = len(x)
    return ((n - 1) * [None]
        + [sum(x[i:i + n]) / n for i in range(L - n + 1)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 1))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 2))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 3))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 4))
```

Fast solution with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

def moving_average(x, n, centered=False):
    # prepare input
    x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)
    L = len(x)
    assert L >= n

    # prepare output variable
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    result[:n-1] = np.nan

    # moving average:
    result[n-1:] = sum([x[n-i-1:L-i] for i in range(n)]) / n

    if centered:
        result = np.hstack((result[n//2:], result[:n//2]))

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 1))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 2))
    print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 3))
    try:
        print(moving_average([1, 2, 3], 4))
    except AssertionError:
        print("Rightly failed...")
```

From my data wokshop: https://github.com/ChaoticRoman/numpy_scipy_matplotlib_workshop

Your code fixed:

```py
def moving_average(x, n):
    i=0
    ma=[]

    if i < n - 1:
        ma += [None] * (n-1-i)  # fixed here

    while i < len(x) - n + 1:
        nn = x[i:i+n]
        n_average = sum(nn)/n
        ma.append(n_average)
        i=i+1

    return ma  # added
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am just an entry-level. Could you do it in a simpler way? or could you tell me anything wrong with my previous code?

Comment: @kris, simpler way added, your code made working.